# Does a property of Xor like this exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a property on Xor that says basically $a = b \oplus (a \oplus b)$?  I was thinking associative but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Did you try building a truth table?

Comment: @CameronWilliams No, I haven't learned about those yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s actually a consequence of four properties of $\oplus$: it’s associative, it’s commutative, $x\oplus x=0$ for all $x$, and $0$ is an identity for $\oplus$. The derivation is simple:

$$b\oplus(a\oplus b)=b\oplus(b\oplus a)=(b\oplus b)\oplus a=0\oplus a=a\;.$$